# How to check for duplicate on specific column?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to detect duplicates on column("G") of my input workbook and by using lastrow of its data at column("E") to merge upwards by using & "" & after which it will delete the entireRow and this process continue until there are no more duplicates.

[image]

[image]

I tried and also look up for many codes including delete and duplicates but I am still having trouble.

```
Dim myCell As Range, myRow As Integer, myRange As Range, myCol As Integer, X As Integer

    'Count number column

Set wsInput = Workbooks("InputB.xls").Worksheets("HC_MODULAR_BOARD_20180112")

     myCol = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(3, 7).End(xlDown)).Count

     'Loop each column to check duplicate values & highlight them.

     For X = 3 To myRow
     Set myRange = Range(Cells(2, X), Cells(myRow, X))

     For Each myCell In myRange
     If Workbooks("InputB.xls").Worksheets("HC_MODULAR_BOARD_20180112").CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
     myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If
     Next
     Next


'  allow values at Column"E" to merge upwards and delete all duplicate and its row (missing)
```

I have no clue how to delete after copying data on top of the column. Someone please help.

Many Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Andrian could you please upload a photo of you data before and after the process to get an idea of what do you want?

Comment: Both pictures are input. As you can see from the first picture, the one that are highlighted in yellow, under column("G") There's a duplicate data. The second picture is the outcome that I need where the last line of data from the duplicate of column("E") is being copied above at row 1 (C4) in case you can't see. This is the link to the image  ---  https://imgur.com/a/K53xORZ

Comment: Please, @adrian edit your question and add the images to your question.

Comment: I can’t add image due to low rep sorry bout that

Comment: Your code is not complete. It just highlights the duplicates. It does not delete or merge anything.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is non-duplicate data in columns other than **E**?  For example, would you want to add the quanities in column D?  Or concatenate the strings in other columns?

Comment: If there's no duplicate, then it will copy the values to another worksheet. I have already done this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long, Counter As Long
    Dim SearchValue As String, AddValue As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Always select your worksheet name

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Counter = 0
        AddValue = ""
        SearchValue = ""

        For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1

            SearchValue = .Range("C" & i).Value

            If SearchValue <> "" Then

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("C3:C" & LastRow), SearchValue) > 1 Then

                    For y = i To 3 Step -1

                        If .Range("C" & y).Value = SearchValue Then

                            If AddValue = "" Then
                                AddValue = .Range("E" & y).Value
                            Else
                                AddValue = AddValue & ", " & .Range("E" & y).Value
                                .Rows(y).EntireRow.Delete
                                Counter = Counter + 1
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next y

                    .Range("E" & i - Counter).Value = AddValue
                    AddValue = ""
                    SearchValue = ""
                    Counter = 0

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good but I am not sure if the code will be able to know that it is selecting the last duplicate and copying value from column E to its above row and then delete. I am afraid it might not work if theres more than 2 duplicate. I will try and let you know thank you

Comment: Hi error, this works but how to I make C4 on the right side because now is showing C4, C1,C2,C3 instead of C1,C2,C3,C4

Comment: we are looping from the bottom to the top so this is what we are expect!

Comment: hmm is there a way to make the C4 appear at the back? Thanks for your help tho

Comment: Replace *AddValue = AddValue & ", " & .Range("E" & y).Value* with *.Range("E" & y).Value & ", " & AddValue*